# Which server distribution has the best market share?

Tags: linux

I'd like to know linux server distributions market share. Is CentOS still best?
Where should I go to find some reliable documents. - and steadily maintained.

Do you know nice website?

Comment: You should use the system that is the best fit for your situation/problem/knowledge, not the most popular.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A snapshot from the web hosting world:

http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/os-linux/all/all

http://w3techs.com/technologies/history_details/os-linux

[image]

Comment: The usage statistics have changed quite a bit since 2011, consider updating the snapshot!

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would recommend something like Ubuntu server, or Debian if you're comfortable with it. For a web administration interface if you need it, look at [webmin](http://www.webmin.com).

Thanks,
RayQuang

Comment: Yes, I'm comfortable with Ubuntu. But I'd like to choose the server which is used by most people. It will give me many benefits. I need to be sure.

Comment: The great benefit of ubuntu server is that it comes locked down out of the box, you don't have to be a linux vetran to perform the necessary hardening, instead you install only what you need and are far less prone to leaving something open by mistake.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on what you want to do with it.  RedHat and Debian still appear to be the gold standard, with Ubuntu the preference for desktop environment.

RedHat still seems to be the best (and in some cases, only) supported distribution rquired by CAD tool vendors.  What some people do in this case is buy a couple of real RedHat licenses for reference systems, then run most of their farm with cheaper CentOS systems.  If a problem is found on the CentOS system, it is duplicated on the RedHat system, where the CAD vendor will agree to support the issue.

Personally I use CentOS because most of the Linux systems I manage run CentOS.